# How to calculate the sum of even integers between two values in MIPS?

Tags: c, loops, branch, mips

I am confused on how to convert C code to MIPS. I seem to to get the loops confused and I think I am possibly using the wrong command. The C code I made to do this is as follows:

```
int main()
{
   int x, y;
   int sum = 0;
   printf("Please enter values for X and Y:\n ");
   scanf("%d %d",&x,&y);


   if (x > y)
   {
     printf("\n** Error");
     exit(0);
   }
   while (x <= y)
   {
     if (x%2 == 0)
        sum += x;
        x++;
   }
   printf("\nThe sum of the even integers between X and Y is: %d\n\n",sum);

   return 0;
}
```

My attempt at the MIPS translation is as follows:

```
   .data
 Prompt:   .asciiz   "Please enter values for X and Y:\n"
 Result:   .asciiz   "The sum of the even integers between X and Y is: \n"

    .text
 li $v0,4              #load $v0 with the print_string code.
 la $a0, Prompt        #load $a0 with the message to me displayed
 syscall

 li $v0,5              #load $v0 with the read_int code for X
 syscall
 move $t0,$v0

 li $v0,5              #load $v0 with the read_int code for Y
 syscall
 move $t1, $v0

 while:

   slt $t2, $t1,$t0  #$t1 = y   $t0 = x
   li $t3,2
   div $t2,$t3
   beq $t2,$0,else
     add $s1,$s1,$t0      #s1 = s1 + x
     addi $t0,$t0,1       #x++
   j while

else:
   li $v0,4
   la $a0, Result
   syscall

   move $a0,$s1
   li $v0,1
   syscall
```

I think my error is in the loop in my MIPS code. My result keeps producing zero and I think my code is checking the loop and then just jumping to my else statement.

After further work, I got it to calculate the sum of all integers and I'm not exactly sure why it is doing so. Here is my most recent update:

```
while:

   sle $t2, $t0,$t1     #$t1 = y   $t0 = x
   li $t3,2        #t3 = 2
   div $t2,$t3       #$t2/2
   beq $t2,$0, else   #if ($t2/2 == 0), jump to the else, otherwise do else
     add $s1,$s1,$t0      #s1 = s1 + x
     addi $t0,$t0,1      #x++
   j while
```

So now, if I enter 1 and 5, it calculates 1 and 3 is gives me 6 instead of just the even sum which should be just 2.

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question, the main confusion was with the the branches. I now understand that they kind of work like opposites so for example, I had to set the "beq" in my while loop to bnez so it would do the calculations when $t2 was != 0. Another minor fix was adding the increment outside of the loop. So, when $t2 != 0, I jump to my "else" which then incremented to find the next number. However, if the remainder was 0, it did the math of sum=sum + x. In conclusion, the main confusion came from thinking opposite about the branches. I now understand that if I wanted to say:

while(a1 < a2)

I would have to write it as

```
while:
 bgeu $a1,$a2, done
   addi "whatever"
 b while

done:
      do done stuff
```

Before this understanding, I was writing it as ble $a1,$a2,done and that is not the way it is to be typed. Logically, that says if a1 < a2...but it is really saying if a1 < a2, jump to the "done" and skip calculations. So I just had to think opposite.